# OAUTH for google wave @googlewave.com addresses

Tags: oauth, google-wave

Is there a way to use google's OAUTH to find an @googlewave.com account name?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the [Google Wave Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/wavedataapi/index.html) which uses OAuth to operate on behalf of an @googlewave.com account name?